# Site list for mailman missing, despite it being created and configured

Tags: mailman

I am migrating a mailman installation from an Ubuntu 8.0.4 server to an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I have succesfully installed mailman on the target server and copied the `data`, `archives` and `lists` directories there as per [this article](http://techfromthetrenches.org/2010/02/26/mailman-migration-is-faster-than-you-think/).

Then I tried `sudo service mailman start` and was greeted with

```
KeyError: 'ee'
 * Site list for mailman missing (looking for list named 'mailman').
 * Please create it; until then, mailman will refuse to start.
```

When I tried to create the mailman list with `bin\newlist mailman` (as per the [official documentation](http://www.list.org/mailman-install/site-list.html)) it tells me that the list `mailman` already exists. Trying to start or restart fails.

So I changed the mm_cfg.py file, as per the documentation again, and set

```
real_name = 'Mailman2'
```

Giving the command

```
/var/lib/mailman$ sudo bin/config_list -i data/sitelist.cfg mailman2
```

yields:

> Non-standard property restored: personalize

which sounds like things worked.
However when I try `sudo service mailman start`, I get the same warning for the list mailman2:

```
KeyError: 'ee'
 * Site list for mailman missing (looking for list named 'mailman2').
 * Please create it; until then, mailman will refuse to start.
```

How can I create a "site list" for mailman and start the mailman service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the list it’s asking for:

`/var/lib/mailman/bin/newlist mailman2`

Comment: As I recall, that's what we did - create the list, and delete it afterwards. The "ee" seemed to originate from a language code (Ewe); not sure where that came from, the entire system was set up for English (en).